# Como ler duas linhas por vez de um arquivo de texto?

Tags: php

tenho um arquivo de texto onde preciso ler duas linhas por vez a cada iteração do loop. Com esse resultado vou montar um json. Exemplo simples:

Tenho um arquivo de texto:

```
JOAO PEREIRA
00000000000
PEDRO SILVA
11111111111
MARIA SOUSA
33333333333
```

Preciso ler de duas em duas linhas de forma que eu consiga cortar as strings e colocar isso dentro de um array para depois montar o json. A saída disso vai ficar assim:

```
"Registros": [
        {
            "nome": "Joao",
            "sobrenome:": "PEREIRA",
            "cpf:": "0000000000"
        },
        {
            "nome": "PEDRO",
            "sobrenome:": "SILVA",
            "cpf:": "1111111111"
        },
        {
            "nome": "MARIA",
            "sobrenome:": "SOUSA",
            "cpf:": "3333333333"
        }
```

Comment: Se fosse para linha uma linha por vez, como você faria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue uma sugestão de código em PHP para você realizar a leitura de duas em duas linhas:

```
$txt - "arquivo.txt";
$hTxt = fopen($txt, 'r');

while (!feof($hTxt)) {
   $linha = fgets($hTxt);
   $nome1 = '';
   $nome2 = '';
   $cpf   = '';

   if (!feof($hTxt)) {
      $nome = explode(' ', $linha);
      $nome1 = $nome[0];
      $nome2 = $nome[1];

      $linha = fgets($hTxt);
      if (!feof($hTxt)){
         $cpf = $linha;
      }
   }

   // Aqui você joga o valor no JSON, para ler as próximas duas linhas
}
```

Comment: Não entendi esse laço interno. Por que você percorre o arquivo inteiro de novo para definir `$cpf`? Nesse caso `$cpf` sempre seria a última linha e o laço externo iria se encerrar logo após a primeira iteração, visto que você já atingiu o fim do arquivo.

Comment: Anderson, corrigi o código. Realmente não era necessário um segundo laço, apenas uma leitura da próxima linha. Obrigado.

Comment: Mas a verificação para saber se existe uma próxima linha será bastante útil caso o arquivo tenha uma quantidade ímpar de linhas :D

Comment: Sim, Anderson, concordo. Tanto que ampliei o código para limpar as variáveis e ir verificando... Obrigado pelo apontamento!

Answer (score 0):

OBS: O código a seguir não funciona muito bem com arquivos muito grandes e a quebra de linha pode mudar de dependendo do sistema operacional (onde o arquivo está), é apenas uma alternativa utilizando algumas funções de array do php, se for utilizar esteja ciente disso.

```
 <?php
        //Extrai linhas do arquivo
        $contents = file_get_contents('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/master/Passwords/Common-Credentials/10-million-password-list-top-100.txt');
        //Separa as linhas em um array
        $pieces = explode("\n", $contents);
        //Junta as linhas de 3 em 3
        $chunk = array_chunk($pieces, 3);
        //mapeia as linhas (operador de coalescência nula (??) disponível em PHP >=7)
        $map = array_map(function ($record) {
            return ["nome" => $record[0] ?? null, "cpf" => $record[1] ?? null, "sobrenome" => $record[2] ?? null];
        }, $chunk);
        //exibe json final
        echo json_encode($map);
```